# The ± 2 window in Word similarity of NLP

Tags: vector, nlp, distribution

There is a question illustrate below:

//--------question start---------------------

Consider the following small corpus consisting of three sentences:

`The judge struck the gavel to silence the court. Buying the cheap saw is false
economy. The nail was driven in when the hammer struck it hard.`

Use distributional similarity to determine whether the word gavel is more similar in mean-
ing to hammer or saw . To compute distributional similarity you must (1) use bag-of-words
in **a ± 2 window** around the target as features, (2) not alter the context words in any way
(e.g. by stemming or removing stop words) and (3) use the Dice measure to compare
the feature vectors. Make sure to show all stages of your working.

//--------question end---------------------

I don't understand what is a ± 2 window in (1). Would someone explain for me? Thank you guys very much.

Comment: I'm guessing that means a range of 2 words around the target word. So for "struck", that would include from "the"  to "gavel".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ± 2 window means 2 words to the left and 2 words to the right of the target word. For target word "silence", the window would be ["gavel", "to", "the", "court"], and for "hammer", it would be ["when", "the", "struck", "it"].